# springroo upgrades

Tags: spring-roo

Hello
when I start springroo console, it says me

> 18 upgrades available (plus 0 upgrade not visible due to your version stability setting of RELEASE)

so today it's already 18, yesterday it was 16, but how can I apply that updates?

Answer (score 0):

That is updates about addons installed in springroo and they can be applied using command `addon upgrade all`

Answer (score 0):

addon upgrade settings --addonStabilityLevel ANY|MILESTONE|RELEASE|RELEASE_CANDIDATE